# Safer way to extract future result

Tags: scala, future

```
     for {
        Some(article) <- articleService.get(id) // returns Future[Option[Article]]
        Some(account) <- accountService.get(article.authorId) // resturns Future[Option[Account]]
      } yield ArticleDetail(article, account)
```

This way is pretty straight forward but not safe, because the `Some(article)` and `Some(account)`  may throw `NoSuchElementException`

Of course we can use `flatMap` to rewrite it like this

```
articleService.get(id).flatMap {
  case Some(article) => accountService.get(article.authorId).map(ArticleDetail(article, _))
  case None =>
    Future.successful(None)
}
```

But not so straight forward

Is there a safe and simple way to do this ?

Comment: where is your `Future` ?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta I've make comment to that the two service return future

Comment: See also `Using a Scalaz monad transformer` [here](http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/scala-compose-option-future/).